# How can I install Postgres drivers for gorm with gin?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have tried to connect Gin application to Postgres database, both dockerized. I encounter an error while installing Postgres driver. Config is described on the [website](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html):

```
$ go get -u gorm.io/driver/postgres
go: downloading gorm.io/gorm v1.24.2
go: downloading github.com/jackc/pgx/v5 v5.3.1
go: downloading github.com/jackc/pgx v3.6.2+incompatible
gorm.io/driver/postgres imports
        github.com/jackc/pgx/v5 imports
        github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype imports
        net/netip: package net/netip is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/net/netip)
```

It seems that package net/netip is not in GOROOT. As I found it should be here by default. What has happened?

My Go version is 1.17.6

```
$ go version
go version go1.17.6 linux/amd64
```

Comment: Upgrade to at least 1.18. See https://go.dev/doc/go1.18#netip.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I have decided to update to 1.20 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to at least to the 1.18 version, may be that is the issue